# PYTHON- how are the two ELSE interfering with the two IF

Tags: python

```
def completar_tablero (cursor, tablero, barco, sentido):
    tupla, radio=cursor
    x, y=tupla
    print tupla
    for i in range(0, 10):
        if x>203+33*i and x<233+33*i:
            print i
            for p in range(0, 10):
                if y>53+33*p and y<53+33*p+30:
                    print p
                    casillas=(i, p)
                    print casillas
                else:
                    casillas=(-1, -1)   
        else:
            casillas=(-1, -1)           
    print casillas 
    return casillas
```

This function receives coordinates as a input, and is supposed to return a column and a row, whose areas are defined by the for cycle. 
The issue is that this function always returns the (-1, -1) tuple. I used some prints trying to pinpoint the problem, and I noticed that after the second `for`, the 'casillas' variable is correctly defines, but is then replaced by the one in the first else.
Can someone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [tour]. Did you notice that your post does not appear as you (hopefully) meant it to? There is a preview when entering questions, and editing help is available in that same screen. Also: consider a better title please.

Comment: If you always execute the else clause, then the if cannot ever be true.  Check your assumptions.  It's not Python; it's you.

Comment: Check the order of operations in your if statement. Try adding parenthesis. I don't know exactly what you were going for, but grouping the numerical operands with parenthesis will help to make sure that python is executing the math you intend it to.

Comment: @duffymo i don't think i understand. Can you give me an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @duffymo your assumptions are wrong in some point as this values (among many other) give expected (?) results, ie. not returning (-1,-1):

```
x   y   : returns
529 366 : (9, 9)
529 367 : (9, 9)
529 368 : (9, 9)
529 369 : (9, 9)
529 370 : (9, 9)
529 371 : (9, 9)
529 372 : (9, 9)
```

You can test it with this code (i've simplified your function removing not used variables):

```
def completar_tablero (x,y):
    for i in range(0, 10):
        if x>203+33*i and x<233+33*i:
            for p in range(0, 10):
                if y>53+33*p and y<53+33*p+30:
                    casillas=(i, p)
                else:
                    casillas=(-1, -1)   
        else:
            casillas=(-1, -1)           
    return casillas

for x in range(0,1000):
    for y in range(0,1000):
        z = completar_tablero (x,y)
        if z[0]!=-1 and z[1]!=-1:
            print x,y,":",z
```

Comment: thanks!! now i understand :)) i wasn't considering that the for cycle continued after defining the variable as i wanted it to. it was so simple!